# jQuery load() before form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

On my form submit, I'm trying to use load() to run a PHP script, add data to my database, then submit the form on completion. However, if the form submits true, the data isn't added to my database, but if it returns false, it is. Here's basically what I'm looking at:

```
if(//form not empty){
    $j('#allset').load(url, function(){
        return true;
    });
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I don't know if it matters, but the form I'm trying to submit is a paypal form.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: How are you testing if the form is not empty?

Comment: Can we see your actual function instead of your pseudo code, because in your pseudo code, at least, you have your second paran and first curly brace commented out.

Comment: unless you haven't changed the code after copying it here, what @Canuteson said must be the problem

Comment: Is this codes executed on sumbit() for the form? If so - it will not work, because it will not wait for the "return true" in the load() callback, as it's executed later, when the Ajax request completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning `true` from the callback will have no effect. The event handler will return immediately after it made the Ajax call. It will not wait for the call to finish (Ajax is **asynchronous**).

You have prevent form submission in any case and then submit the form again, once the Ajax request is completed. Something like this:

```
(function() {
    var processed = false;

    $(form).submit(function(event){
        if(processed) {            // data sent fo the server?
            processed = false;
            return true;
        }

        event.preventDefault();    // prevent form submission

        if(/* form not empty */) {
            $.get(url, function() { // do you need load?
                processed = true;
                $(form).submit();
            });
        }
    });
}());
```

Comment: I didn't use this exact solution, but I marked it as the answer because it's still correct. I did something like this instead:
`$('.submit').click(function(){
return false;
if(/*form not empty*/){
$('#allset').load(url, function() { $('#form').submit(); });
}
});`

Comment: @HWD: Yeah, I also thought about this one. But keep in mind that forms can also be submitted by pressing the enter key...